# A Performance in passing big data from C++ to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a question related to the performance. I want to pass from C++ side vector of structures to qml side, where vector contains about 3000 elements and structure 14 elements. Basically I can create 14 containers with e.g. QVariantLists filled with data and call 4 functions(e.g. QObject::invokeMethod) to pass that data. I can also call QObject::invokeMethod 3000 times where I pass just QVariantList, so what is the best solution in this case ?

2. Is there any way to pass from C++ side structure with 14 elements to qml with directly casting it to some qml or js object ?

Comment: You don't "pass" the 3000 element list to QML.  You create ListView in QML and create a C++ data model for the ListView to query from as elements scroll on to the screen.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your use-case but you can pass all the data at once, as array of arrays:

**C++**

```
QVariantList list;
for(int i = 0;i < 10;i ++) {
    QList<int> sublist;
    sublist.append(i * 1);
    sublist.append(i * 2);
    sublist.append(i * 3);
    list.append(QVariant::fromValue(sublist));
}

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));


QObject *root = engine.rootObjects().first();
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(root, "printArrays", Qt::DirectConnection,
                           Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(list)));
```

**QML** (main.qml)

```
Window {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    visible: true

    function printArrays(arr)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var subarr = arr[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < subarr.length; j++) {
                console.info(subarr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for performance, I think that passing data wrapped in `QVariant` isn't efficient at all. Instead you can create some proxy object in C++ and expose it to QML either with `setContextProperty` or `qmlRegisterType`.